# On flash builder 4.7 - how can I get my file to run from a web address and not from file://

Tags: flash, flash-builder, flashbuilder4

I need to access some services, such as facebook, from the containing HTML and I keep getting blocked because I'm running things locally...
What do I need to do in order for the webpage that's launched when I debug the project to run from http://www.something.com?

Comment: blocked how? by service or flash player?